# How to retrieve granted privileges without access to the database “mysql”?

Tags: mysql, permissions

As a MySQL user without access to the *mysql* database, is it possible to retrieve my privileges?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that using [`SHOW GRANTS`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/show-grants.html) did work in this case:

```
SHOW GRANTS FOR CURRENT_USER;
```

Although the manual states that you still need to have access to the *mysql* database:

> `SHOW GRANTS` requires the `SELECT` privilege for the *mysql* database.

And accessing *mysql.user* directly actually didn’t work, probably because it does also contain further sensitive information like the passwords of other users:

> ```
> mysql> SELECT * FROM mysql.user;
> ERROR 1142 (42000): SELECT command denied to user 'user'@'host' for table 'user'
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have read-only access to the /var/lib/mysql/mysql folder, here is a hacker's approach, without disrupting the running server and without exposing any passwords:

Step 1) Install MySQL on your Windows machine. Make sure it is the same version number of MySQL as the Linux version.

Step 2) Shutdown mysql on the Windows machine:
C:\> net stop mysql

Step 3) Download the mysql schema from the Linux server and store the individual files in the mysql subfolder on the Window machine. The mysql schema contains various MyISAM and CSV files.

Step 4) Add the line 'skip-grant-tables' to my.ini on your Windows machine

Step 5) Startup mysql on the Windows machine
C:\> net start mysql

Step 6) Run mysql client on the Windows machine (no password needed at this point)

Step 7) Run this command in the mysql client

INSERT INTO mysql.user SET
                  Host = 'localhost',
                  User = 'myhackeruser',
              Password = PASSWORD('whatever'),
           Select_priv = 'Y',
           Insert_priv = 'Y',
           Update_priv = 'Y',
           Delete_priv = 'Y',
           Create_priv = 'Y',
             Drop_priv = 'Y',
           Reload_priv = 'Y',
         Shutdown_priv = 'Y',
          Process_priv = 'Y',
             File_priv = 'Y',
            Grant_priv = 'Y',
       References_priv = 'Y',
            Index_priv = 'Y',
            Alter_priv = 'Y',
          Show_db_priv = 'Y',
            Super_priv = 'Y',
 Create_tmp_table_priv = 'Y',
      Lock_tables_priv = 'Y',
          Execute_priv = 'Y',
       Repl_slave_priv = 'Y',
      Repl_client_priv = 'Y',
      Create_view_priv = 'Y',
        Show_view_priv = 'Y',
   Create_routine_priv = 'Y',
    Alter_routine_priv = 'Y',
      Create_user_priv = 'Y',
           max_questions = 0,
             max_updates = 0;

Step 8) Shutdown mysql on the Windows machine:
C:\> net stop mysql

Step 9) Startup mysql on the Windows machine:
C:\> net start mysql

Step 10) Run mysql client as myhackeruser:
C:\> mysql -umyhackeruser -pwhatever

Step 11) Run "SHOW GRANTS FOR 'whateveruserid'@'whateverhost';"

It's a long-winded approach but it works.

Give it a Try !!!